# Getting an error when trying to call a setter method

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, I'm trying to just play around with some different lines of code, this is what I have so far:

**CardGame.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CardGameViewController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL flipped;

@end
```

And my

**CardGame.m**

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"


@interface CardGameViewController ()

@end


@implementation CardGameViewController

@synthesize flipped;

- (IBAction)cardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%d", flipped);
    [setFlipped: true];
}

@end
```

I get an error saying `Use of undeclared identifier 'setFlipped'` from what I read, calling `@synthesize` should create a setter/getter behind the scenes so I'm not sure why that's not working. Any idea how I can set this boolean value to true, and why what I have now does not work?

Comment: Should that be `[self setFlipped:true];` or just `self.flipped = true;`?

Comment: One other thing - why does your `CardGameViewController` extend `NSObject`? Given the name of the class it should extend `UIViewController` (or some other variant). Class names should reflect what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[setFlipped: true]` is invalid syntax.  A method call with one parm is `[object methodName:parm]`.  You didn't provide an object, and without an object the method cannot be identified.